# Windows Update history missing after installing an update to a preview build

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-preview, windows-insider

Windows Update says it's installed an update to this preview build:

[image]

...but the installed update history doesn't show it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Preview Builds are completely new Windows versions, so update history was deleted.

[To see which older preview builds you had installed](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.deskmodder.de%2Fblog%2F2017%2F03%2F04%2Fwie-viele-windows-10-insider-versionen-hab-ich-schon-installiert-kann-man-in-der-registry-nachsehen%2F&edit-text=) on that machine, open regedit.exe, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup` and under each `Source OS (Updated on….)` key you see which older preview builds you had installed

[image]

Comment: However, this wasn't a new preview build. I've had plenty of those, but this said it was just a feature update to the existing build.

Comment: what was your older Build version?

Comment: so what was your old build? 15063?